# How to pass a sql file to gcloud sql export instead of inline sql?

Tags: sql, gcloud

I can export my data using

```
gcloud sql export csv .... --query='SELECT * FROM mytable'
```

My SELECT sql command is long and I'd like to pass it to gcloud in a file. I couldn't find anything in the docs about that. Is this possible to pass a file?

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/import-export-csv#gcloud

Comment: Are you trying to pass the name of the ‘SELECT’ file into the file in gcloud?

Comment: yes @AndresFiescoCasasola, or it's content. The goal is to keep the SELECT statement in a separate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using options shown here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393351/pass-contents-of-file-as-argument-to-bash-script

This worked:

> --query="$(<myFile.sql)"

The answer @Piotr W. provided was just missing quotations.

Worth noting this method allowed me to put my SELECT statement with line breaks in a file vs providing the SELECT statement inline that could not have line breaks, making it hard to read and update.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
gcloud sql export csv .... --query=$(< x.sql)
```

where x.sql is the file with the SELECT statement.

Comment: ERROR: (gcloud.sql.export.csv) unrecognized arguments:
  add-google-cloud-ops-agent-repo.sh
  inventory
  keys
  linux_amd64.tar.gz
  sftp-gcs
  snap
  test.sql
  from
  shopify
  limit
  5;
  To search the help text of gcloud commands, run:
  gcloud help -- SEARCH_TERMS